# Location of MFT file?

Tags: windows, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I have a partition, formatted as NTFS. I have studied that devices formatted as NTFS have a MFT (Master File Table) which contains a lot of information about the contents of a devices.

Is MFT really a file?
Where is it located?
How can I view it?

I, actually want to view the $BITMAP to know the locations of all the files and directories in a partition.

Update:
Seems like I can only view the MFT file using HexEditor. Still searching for more options though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a disk's cluster BITMAP can be read via the [FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364573(VS.85).aspx) API call. However, it won't tell what files are at each cluster. You need either parse the MFT (faster) or recursively call [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364572(VS.85).aspx) on each file (slow).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to list files from a drive and view the path of them then check the source files here [a link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfs-search/files/?source=navbar). This guy parses the MFT and searches for a file present inside it or not. Just modify the code can help you get the path of files and directories.

Answer (score -2):

I don't exactly know where it is but you can try next path `\\.\C:`, as I understood it is it. You can h[ave a look on this program](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsvolumeapis1_22.html) that shows how to get deleted files.

Answer (score -6):

MFT is not a file. MFT is a part of the file system. To view it, you will have to access disk on lower level, such as block mode.